# Vscode error: Failed to start the Kernel ——Cannot Find module './351.node.js'

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

It shows Cannot Find module './351.node.js'.
I have installed Jupyter in Vscode and got ipykernel for my env--'pytorch',but the kernel cannot start. other env also have the same problem.
Thanks!

May be the reason I just create a new env?  but the pip path is isolated,and it looks like the error of vscode but conda.
I also have reinstalled the vscode ,but it didn't work.

I hope a solution and a reason ,the reason why the doc cannot be found,and the solution to solve it.
Thanks!

Comment: I found the reason!
I solved it after replace the jupyter extension with its last version. 
emmmm，it was published a mounth ago.